# Keeping count in a recursive function? [Jython]

Tags: python, recursion, jython

I'm trying to count the number of times the letter 'x' appears in a string using a recursive function. My function currently does this, however I wish to have only one parameter (the string). I am having difficulty creating a counter that is not overwritten when the function is iterated in the return line.

To illustrate what I mean:

```
def xCounter(string): <br>
 **counter = 0** (This resets the counter to 0 with each iteration)  <br>
    if len(string) == 0: 
       return counter 
    elif string[0] == 'x': 
       counter = counter + 1  
    elif string[0] != 'x': 
       return xCounter(string[1:],counter) 
   return xCounter(string[1:],counter)
```

> xCounter("gfljkgfxlkjsfxxljsx")
>
> > 0

The only way I have it working so far is defining counter as a parameter:

```
def xCounter(string, counter):  <br>
   if len(string) == 0: <br>
      return counter <br>
   elif string[0] == 'x': <br>
      counter = counter + 1  <br>
   elif string[0] != 'x': <br>
      return xCounter(string[1:],counter) <br>
   return xCounter(string[1:],counter) <br>
```

> xCounter("werixiuewrxiewx",0)
>
> > 3

Can anyone please provide me some insight on how to keep count in this function without overwriting the count or defining count as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Return the recursive call, plus 1 if the character is present. The counter in this case would either be a 0 or a 1; instead of a running total.

You could set a Boolean variable to whether or not the current character is an 'x', then you can change the last line to something like:

```
return xCounter[1:] +
    (if isX then 0 else 1)
```

The end result will be a chain of addition expressions, where the end result (an addition "chain" of 1s and 0s) is returned.

You could also wrap the "workhorse"  function in a wrapper that automatically passes in the initial parameter so the caller doesn't have to:

```
def xCounter(str):
    return xCounterHelper(str, 0)
```

where `xCounterHelper` is your original function.

In complicated recursive functions that require more parameters, the second option is very handy. Hide the ugly multi-parameter version as a private function (if it's a class method), and expose the cleaner 1 parameter version (note that Python doesn't have private functions. This is more for languages that do).

Comment: Do you actually use Python? `cond ? iftrue : iffalse` isn't valid syntax. You're looking for `iftrue if cond else iffalse`. The second example won't work since `xCounter` doesn't have a second parameter. There are no private functions in Python either.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used Python in like 2 years. Can you not overload functions in Python? If you read my second example, you'll see it's referring to an overload, not the same function. Even if it doesn't have overloads (my bad), it's still a valid technique. The wrapper function should then just take the pretty name, while the work function has an identifier tagged onto it. And the private comment was a general comment; not about Python specifically.

Comment: @Navith I've addressed your concerns.

Comment: I think your suggestion is similar to Hrvoje's. This sounds like the most logical solution, thank you both for helping me see it.

Comment: @NicWatkins His example is much cleaner than mine. I'd accept his. Keep my second example in mind though if you ever start doing more complicated recursion.

Comment: Rather than having a separate helper function, it would be more natural in Python to use an optional argument: `def xCounter(str, count=0): ...`.  Optional arguments and defaults in Python address some of the use-cases for function and method overloading in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're doing this for exercise in recursion, not for actual solution, right?  The right way to do it in python would be

```
count = "gfljkgfxlkjsfxxljsx".count('x')
print count
```

However, you are correct in that your code resets the counter with each iteration, it's supposed to.

There are ways (like global variables) to keep track of the counter without using it as a parameter, but that's BAD BAD BAD.  The extra parameter is the way to do it right.

Comment: Yes this is for a basic computing computer science course I am taking. I'll try it using the count function and thank you for the reassurance on the extra parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def xCounter(string): 
    if len(string) == 0: return 0     
    return (string[0]=='x') + xCounter(string[1:])
```

... if you reach the end of a string, you return 0, otherwise you return 0 or 1 (depending whether string[0] is 'x') plus the function value for the rest of the string... you sum all these numbers in the end and get your answer!

Of course, that's not how it's done, but it's a good practice in recursive functions.

You can even do it shorter, like a lambda:

```
f=lambda s:len(s) and (s[0]=='x') + f(s[1:]) or 0
```

Comment: That's a great idea. I never considered returning the number I wished to sum with, and then adding all of the returned values together. Thank you!